# Concurrent matrix sum - past Exam paper

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, floating-point, gpu, cpu-architecture

I'm currently studying in my 3rd year of university - my exam for Computer Systems and Concurrency and I'm confused about a past paper question. Nobody - even the lecturer - has answered my question.

Question:

> `Consider the following GPU that consists of 8 multiprocessors clocked at 1.5 GHz, each of which contains 8 multithreaded single-precision floating-point units and integer processing units. It has a memory system that consists of 8 partitions of 1GHz  Graphics DDR3DRAM, each 8 bytes wide and with 256 MB of capacity. Making reasonable assumptions (state them), and a naive matrix  multiplication algorithm, compute how much time the computation C = A * B would take. A, B, and C are n * n matrices and n is determined by the amount of memory the system has.`

Answer given in solutions:

```
> Assuming it has a single-precision FP multiply-add instruction,   
 Single-precision FP multiply-add performance =   
 \#MPs * #SP/MP * #FLOPs/instr/SP * #instr/clock * #clocks/sec =  
8 * 8 * 2 * 1 * 1.5 G = 192 GFlops / second   
Total DDR3RAM memory size = 8 * 256 MB = 2048 MB 
The peak DDR3 bandwidth =   #Partitions * #bytes/transfer * #transfers/clock * #clocks/sec = 8 * 8 * 2 * 1G = 128 GB/sec  

>Modern computers have 32-bit single precision So, if we want 3 n*n SP matrices, 
maximum n is  
3n^2 * 4 <= 2048 * 1024 * 1024

>nmax = 13377 = n

>The number of operations that a naive mm algorithm (triply nested loop) needs is calculated as follows:   
>For each element of the
 result, we need n multiply-adds For each row of the result, 

>we need n * n multiply-adds  For the entire result matrix, we need n * n * n multiply-adds Thus, approximately 2393 GFlops.  

> Assuming no cache, we have loading of 2 matrices and storing of 1 to the graphics memory.

>That is 3 * n^2 = 512 GB of data.  This process will take 512 / 128 = 4 seconds   
Also, the processing will take 2393 / 192 = 12.46 seconds   Thus the
 entire matrix multiplication will take 16.46 seconds.
```

Now my questions is - how does the calculation of 3*((13377)^2) = 536,832,387

translate to 536,832,387 = 512 GB.

That is 536.8 Million values. Each value is 4 bytes long. The memory interface is 8 bytes wide - assuming the GPU cannot fetch 2 values and split them - that effectively doubles the size of the reads and writes. Therefore the 2GB of Memory used is effectively read/written twice (because 8 bytes are read and 4 ignored) Therefore only 4GB of data is passed between the RAM and the GPU.

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong as the only way I can think of is that 536.8 Million Result is the value of the memory operations in KB - which is not stated anywhere.

Comment: It looks like the person developing the answer confused ~512 *Mi* 4-byte values with 512 *GiB*. The problem is poorly solved because a mostly naive (register allocating each C[i][j] but not blocking or transposing B) matrix multiply without caching would read each element of A and B *n* times. In addition, although A could be read as a contiguous stream (exploiting the SIMD nature of a GPU), B would only be able to read one element per memory access; since GDDR3 has a burst length of 4, only 4B of the 32B transferred for B would be used (huge waste of bandwidth).

Comment: Not having memory access and computation overlap in time also seems to be a strange assumption. (Overall, the provided solution looks *very* sloppy.)